# jQuery File Upload with Symfony / Twig

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I am trying to implement the Basic Plus UI example from the jquery file upload [demo page](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) within my Symfony2 project.
The problem is, that Twig throws an error when i use the script language 'text/x-tmpl' provided by blueimp within my body block:

```
 Unexpected character ";" in library/Book/new.html.twig at line 162
```

How can i implement the jquery file upload basic plus UI example in a twig template, so that the code within 'text/x-tmpl' does not throw an error ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in twig docs, damn i overread that ..
[verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)